# How to put biggest 32bit integer into a register file

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I need to put the biggest int to a register file which is(+2147483647) (0x7FFFFFFF)

```
.data

 input : .word 0x7FFFFFFF #+ infinity

 .text
  la $a0, input

  move $t0, $a0
```

the input label can hold this value however, I cant transfer it to $a0 and $a0 becomes 268500992.

```
lui $a0, 0x7FFF
ori $a0, 0xFFFF
```

can work but I need to take argument from .data segment.
Can you guys offer me a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`move $t0, $a0` copies the value of `$a0` into `$t0`. So what you're getting is the address of `input`, not the value at that address.

What you want is to load a word (32 bits) from memory, i.e. `lw $t0, ($a0)`.

Comment: How could I missed that I think I'm loosing my mind thank you ".data

input : .word 0x7FFFFFFF #+ infinity

.text

la $s0, input
lw $a0, 0($s0)" worked